# Scrolling UICollectionView to end on loading the viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell`. When i scroll to that `UITableViewCell`, i want the `UICollectionView` in it to be scroll to last cell automatically only on initial launch of viewController.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the below given suggestions but the code crashes on that as i guess the collection view is not build up till that point.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by call this code in viewWillAppear :

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need implement scrolling to the end of `UICollectionView` instance in `cellForRow:atIndexPath:` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.collectionView scroll...];
    return cell;
}
```